# Google API file create permissions

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive-api

Hi I am creating a new google drive file via the PHP SDK like so :

```
$driveService = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

$fileMetadata = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile(array(
        'name' => $filename,
    'parents' => array('root')));
$content = file_get_contents($filepath.'.csv');
$file = $driveService->files->create($fileMetadata, array(
'data' => $content,
'mimeType' => 'text/csv',
'uploadType' => 'media'));
```

And setting it's permissions.

```
$user_email = $driveService->about->get(array('fields' => 'user'))->getUser()->getemailAddress();
$userPermission = new Google_Service_Drive_Permission(array(
'type' => 'user',
'role' => 'writer',
'emailAddress' => $user_email
));
$fileMetadata = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile(array(
        'name' => $filename,
    'parents' => array('root')));
$content = file_get_contents($filepath.'.csv');
```

When I try and access the file in the google drive gui, I can see the files but when I try to open/ download them I get a authorisation error:

```
 Access to doc-0g-0c-docs.googleusercontent.com was denied
```

On download Or

```
 Authorisation requeired
```

If I try to open in the google notepad.  I also cannot open them in google docs.

Client set up code :

$client = new Google_Client();

```
    if (!empty(get_option('access_token')) && !$reset) {
    $credentials_file = plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 
    get_option('credentials_filename');

    $client->setAuthConfig($credentials_file);
    $client->setPrompt('select_account consent');
    $client->setApplicationName("Client_Library_Examples");

    $client->addScope(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE);

    $client->setRedirectUri( plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . '/oauth2callback.php');
    $client->setAccessType('offline');        // offline access
    $client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);   
    $client->setAccessToken(get_option('access_token'));
```

Comment: please edit your question and include your code for creating the $client who ever you are logging in as does not have access to that file.

Comment: The account authorized in OAUTH and the one in the google dash are the same.

Comment: Added client set up code